# Origine dell'espressione "essere una mosca bianca"

Tags: phrase-origin

Alcuni giorni fa, su Rai News, ho sentito l'espressione "essere una mosca bianca" in riferimento a un giornalista recentemente scomparso. Si tratta di un modo di dire che non conoscevo. Sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mosca) ne ho trovato il significato:

> *raro come una m. bianca*, o assol. *è una m. bianca*, di cosa rarissima o di persona che abbia qualità assai rare tra gli uomini in generale o tra coloro che sono nelle sue condizioni.

Mi è sembrata un'espressione veramente curiosa perché, a quanto pare, la mosca bianca è un parassita delle piante che può provocare danni importanti nell'agricoltura. Non sono riuscita, però, a trovare nulla sull'origine di questo modo di dire. Qualcuno di voi ne saprebbe qualcosa?

Comment: Nell'accezione comune le mosche sono nere, per cui trovarne una di colore opposto dovrebbe essere un evento estremamente raro, penso che l'espressione derivi da qui.

Comment: In ogni caso, secondo il [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI10/00000987.jpg), l'origine è Settecentesca: la prima attestazione è di Gasparo Gozzi.  Il modo in cui è scritta questa prima attestazione sembra corroborare l'ipotesi di @RiccardoDeContardi.